# Macro query spread over multiple-sheets

Tags: vba, excel

Wording my question is slightly tricky so I've included screen-shots to make this easier. I have 2 separate spreadsheets which are currently not linked together in anyway. What I've been asked to do is:

For the drop-downs which have a * next to them, have this * drop-down get converted into a acronym (I.e. If it's Home Visit *, then this will be converted to HV), and have it automatically entered into Cell Position X. Please refer to Image 1 then Image 2)

[image: Image One][image: Image 2]

So the user would click on Sheet one, select the relevant drop-down field and then assign how much time that task took. The second sheet would then update itself with this information - it would insert the users name, program and activities. This is where it gets very tricky. Based off the drop-down selection, if it is asterisked (*), then based off the field-type it will convert it into a set acronym which would then be placed in one of the data fields based off the entry date that has been provided.

I designed both spread-sheets and they have macros in the background, but I can't seem to work out how to best perform this. Would you suggest a transpose function which checks firstly the date criteria and then an INDEX(MATCH) function to match the criteria against a pre-defined name-range which converts Home Visit etc. to HV automatically? I'm also unsure of how to insert delimiters for each new entry that is read. If anyone can provide help I would be very grateful.[image: Snapshot of Screen1]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but here goes:

What about adding a Worksheet_Change event to look for changes in the drop-down's cell, and then converting it to an acronym?

Place the following code inside the sheet of interest:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'If Cell A1 is changed, put the acronym into A2
    If Target.Row = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
        Cells(2, 1) = GetAcronym(Target.Value)
    End If

End Sub

Function GetAcronym(TheText As String) As String

    Dim result As String
    Dim x As Long

    'Always grab the first letter
    result = Mid(TheText, 1, 1)

    'Get the other letters
    For x = 2 To Len(TheText) - 1
        If Mid(TheText, x, 1) = " " Then result = result & Mid(TheText, x + 1, 1)
    Next x

    GetAcronym = UCase(result)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't know if that would solve the issue however. It's definitely an interesting proposition - but the issue is that there will be multiple entries put in, and they could all be at the same date i.e.John Doe had 3 School Visits and 1 Home visit on the 17th April.

The field would then need to be displayed on the 2nd sheet as: SV,SV,SV,HV.

Comment: Okay, so clearly I didn't get the example you gave.  Here are the questions that would help me clear it up:
1. The first spreadsheet -- how many lines does it have?  Can you enter an unlimited number of entries under the "red headings"?
2. What do you mean by "based off the field-type it will convert it into a set acronym"?  Sometimes it will be an acronym, other times it should just be ignored?
3. How do you know which sheet the value should be added to (the target)?

Comment: Hi D'Noob, I just attached a new screenshot of Sheet 1. It doesn't matter how many lines Sheet 1 has - that's irrelevant. How it works is that, before this Sheet, there is one where I have a macro which asks individuals to enter in the Name of the Client, Case Manager, Contract type Etc. Via a macro this is translated onto Worksheet 1. The individuals will then click and select certain drop-down options (Email, Phone call etc.) and then the graphs on the right will update and calculate some metrics.

Comment: For example, if the item selected is Consultation - Home Visit *, my INDEX(MATCH) would then identify that function as a face-to-face visit and as such it needs to be inserted in Sheet #2. 3. That's a good question - Let me think about how to word that and get back to you..!

Comment: Pretty much. I'll leave it alone for now and get back to it later. Thanks anyway!